# How to bind variable in complex struct dataframes in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a code snippit like this:

```
val filteredDF = df.filter($"abc.color".equalTo("yellow") && $"abc.height".equalTo("5")).toDF()
```

The complex struct looks like:

```
{
  abc:{
      color: yellow,
      height:5
  }
}
```

What I want is to create a variable to represent abc, say

```
val table_name = "abc"
```

and create variables for color and height as well, say

```
val colorField = "color"
val heightField = "height"
```

Then how can I modify the code above to use those new variables?

I tried some ways like

```
df.filter(${table_name+"."+colorField}.equalTo("yellow")
```

and

```
df.filter(($""+table_name+"."+colorField).equalTo("yellow")
```

But neither works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Scala's [String Interpolation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html)

```
val table_name = "abc"
val colorField = "color"
val heightField = "height"

df.show
+----------+
|       abc|
+----------+
|[yellow,5]|
+----------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.filter(col(s"${table_name}.${colorField}").equalTo("yellow")).show

+----------+
|       abc|
+----------+
|[yellow,5]|
+----------+

df.filter(col(s"${table_name}.${colorField}").equalTo("green")).show
+---+
|abc|
+---+
+---+
```